# how to replace Index values in a dataframe by group IDs in r

Tags: r

I have a data frame:

```
    df = read.table(text="index group   S1  S2  S3  S4
    1   A   2   3   4   6
    2   A   3   4   1   6
    3   A   2   4   1   5
    4   B   5   6   2   3
    5   B   6   4   9   10
    6   B   5   4   8   11
    7   B   11  12  8   10
    8   C   11  9   10  12
    9   C   10  8   11  12
    10  C   9   8   11  12
    11  D   8   9   10  12
    12  D   9   10  8   11", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

I would like to replace values of column S1-S4 with values of column 'group', if the value in column S1-S4 match the column "index". 
so the expected result is :

```
    index   S1  S2  S3  S4
    1   A   A   B   B
    2   A   B   A   B
    3   A   B   A   B
    4   B   B   A   A
    5   B   B   C   C
    6   B   B   C   D
    7   D   D   C   C
    8   D   C   C   D
    9   C   C   D   D
    10  C   C   D   D
    11  C   C   C   D
    12  C   C   C   D
```

I can get the result with a loop and match but I am not satisfied the solution.  I appreciate any helps

Comment: Like this `df[, 3:6] <- df$group[unlist(df[, 3:6])]`? It's as simple as subsetting the group column by the (unlisted) indices in columns S1-S4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The the values in the columns S1 ... S4 are indices of `df$group`:

```
df[, -(1:2)] <- lapply(df[-(1:2)], function(x) df$group[x])
# > df
#    index group S1 S2 S3 S4
# 1      1     A  A  A  B  B
# 2      2     A  A  B  A  B
# 3      3     A  A  B  A  B
# 4      4     B  B  B  A  A
# 5      5     B  B  B  C  C
# 6      6     B  B  B  C  D
# 7      7     B  D  D  C  C
# 8      8     C  D  C  C  D
# 9      9     C  C  C  D  D
# 10    10     C  C  C  D  D
# 11    11     D  C  C  C  D
# 12    12     D  C  C  C  D
```

or (if you want only the four last columns):

```
as.data.frame(lapply(df[-(1:2)], function(x) df$group[x]))
#> as.data.frame(lapply(df[-(1:2)], function(x) df$group[x]))
#    S1 S2 S3 S4
# 1   A  A  B  B
# 2   A  B  A  B
# 3   A  B  A  B
# 4   B  B  A  A
# 5   B  B  C  C
# 6   B  B  C  D
# 7   D  D  C  C
# 8   D  C  C  D
# 9   C  C  D  D
# 10  C  C  D  D
# 11  C  C  C  D
# 12  C  C  C  D
```

Comment: The solutions of Ronak and docendo are faster because they do not loop through the columns. The solution of Ronak even compares with `df$index` (for a situation where `df$index` is not identical with the row number)

Answer (score 2):

We can `match` all the values of 4 columns with that of `index` and extract the corresponding `group` value.

```
df[3:6] <- df$group[match(unlist(df[3:6]), df$index)]

df
#   index group S1 S2 S3 S4
#1      1     A  A  A  B  B
#2      2     A  A  B  A  B
#3      3     A  A  B  A  B
#4      4     B  B  B  A  A
#5      5     B  B  B  C  C
#6      6     B  B  B  C  D
#7      7     B  D  D  C  C
#8      8     C  D  C  C  D
#9      9     C  C  C  D  D
#10    10     C  C  C  D  D
#11    11     D  C  C  C  D
#12    12     D  C  C  C  D
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also do this by converting to `matrix`

```
df[-(1:2)] <- setNames(df$group, df$index)[as.matrix(df[-(1:2)])]
df
#   index group S1 S2 S3 S4
#1      1     A  A  A  B  B
#2      2     A  A  B  A  B
#3      3     A  A  B  A  B
#4      4     B  B  B  A  A
#5      5     B  B  B  C  C
#6      6     B  B  B  C  D
#7      7     B  D  D  C  C
#8      8     C  D  C  C  D
#9      9     C  C  C  D  D
#10    10     C  C  C  D  D
#11    11     D  C  C  C  D
#12    12     D  C  C  C  D
```